# User enabled custom Buttons in iOS Widget

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i have seen some famous widgets with user enabled custom Buttons. Is this officially allowed by Apple?

will i run into problems?

**Thank you**

Comment: Please give move information about your problems.

Comment: i have buttons in my widget but its not running smooth. Maybe i shouldn´t put buttons in my widget?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556274/ios-add-button-to-widget-extension/66006151#66006151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines:

"Widgets are highly customizable and can contain buttons, text, layout customizations, images, and more."

So yes, it's allowed.

See full guideline:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/widgets/